# POST other Form objects on button click only if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have multiple forms with different checkboxes. I want to submit all checkbox values from different forms if a checkbox is selected.

My current code is sending all checkbox values irrespective of whether the checkbox is selected or not.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="f2" action="submit.php" method=POST>
<input type="checkbox" name="approve2" value="93545" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit/>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitAll").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var newForm = $("<form action='submit.php' method='POST'></form>");
        $("form input[type='checkbox']").each(function(i, e) {
            newForm.append(
                $("<input type='hidden' />")
                    .attr("name", e.name)
                    .attr("value", e.value)
            );
        });
        $(document.body).append(newForm);
        newForm.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to get on checked `checkboxes`

```
$("form input[type='checkbox']:checked").each
```

Your code would be

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $("#submitAll").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var newForm = $("<form action='submit.php' method='POST'></form>");
        $("form input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i, e) {
            newForm.append(
                $("<input type='hidden' />")
                    .attr("name", e.name)
                    .attr("value", e.value)
            );
        });
        $(document.body).append(newForm);
        newForm.submit();
    });
 });
</script>
```

**Description:** Matches all elements that are checked or selected.

> The :checked selector works for checkboxes, radio buttons, and select
>   elements. For select elements only, use the :selected selector, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).